# kotlin get view from NavigationView header

Tags: kotlin, findviewbyid

I have such variant, but I believe that there is a better way to do this

```
val header = nav_view.getHeaderView(0) as LinearLayout
val userName = header.findViewById(R.id.user_name) as TextView
```

The issue is that when I try to get it just by `user_name`, it is `null`.

Comment: can you please elaborate? post more code. getHeaderView() fn code can help

Answer (score 4):

You might consider using Android-Kotlin extension plugin. In that case your code will be much simpler and would be:

```
val headerView: View = nav_view.getHeaderView(0)
headerView.userNameTxt.text = "Some Value"
```

Answer (score 3):

This might help you and i think that its better way .

```
nav_view.getHeaderView(0).userNameTxt.text
```

This is shortest way to access from header.

Comment: Thanks so much for you answer