# Changing text in broadcast receiver

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using Broadcast Receiver in Kotlin and am trying to change the text of few text views and image views inside the receiver. However the changes are not visible in the app. I have debugged it and can see that the data is present in the variable when I am trying to set it.

UserData class has the data in the fields name, email, avatarName and avatarColor. However none of the text fields or image views display the assigned data.

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(userDataChangeReceiver, IntentFilter(BROADCAST_USER_DATA_CHANGE))
```

```
private val userDataChangeReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {

        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            if (AuthService.isLoggedIn) {
                usernameNavHeader.text = UserData.name
                userEmailNavHeader.text = UserData.email
                val resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(UserData.avatarName, "drawable", packageName)
                userImgNavHeader.setImageResource(resourceId)
                userImgNavHeader.setBackgroundColor(UserData.getAvatarColor(UserData.avatarColor))
                loginBtnNavHeader.text = getString(R.string.logout)
            }
        }
    }
```

```
val userDataChange = Intent(BROADCAST_USER_DATA_CHANGE)
                          LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(userDataChange)
```

Here's the layout

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/userImgNavHeader"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/nav_header_desc"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/loginBtnNavHeader"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/profiledefault" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/usernameNavHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/userImgNavHeader"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/userImgNavHeader"
        tools:text="ABD" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userEmailNavHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/userImgNavHeader"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/usernameNavHeader"
        tools:text="abd@email.com" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginBtnNavHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="loginBtnNavClicked"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Comment: is this code  `if (AuthService.isLoggedIn)` is executed ?

Comment: Yes, I have even set it to true and got the same result.

Comment: How about change `textView` color using this `usernameNavHeader.setBackgroundColor(Color.Red);`

Comment: Doesn't work. Basically any change that I am doing in this block isn't taking effect.

Comment: Is the layout the `headerLayout` of a `NavigationView`? If so you need the root view of the header layout before you can change items, rather than re-writing the answer this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47767073/4252352 will get what you need to work.

Comment: I have debugged it to see that the control enters the blocks. I have also tried it without the block and hard coded values and it still didn't work.

Comment: @MarkKeen yes it is.

Comment: @MarkKeen Thanks for the link. However, it is still not working

Comment: Then you have a problem elsewhere in your code if you are correctly referencing a `ViewGroup` (and its children) that is your `headerLayout` which is part of a `NavigationView` in your current view hierarchy.

Comment: After hours of searching the web, finally it worked. Thank you John Joe and Mark Keen for your help.

Solution - Gave the nav header layout an id in the NavigationView and used fields using this id.